# Why does this C program completely skip my input?

Tags: c

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {

    int nums[100], i;
    char answer;
    int count = 0;
    double avg;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
        printf("Another? ");
        scanf("%c", &answer);
        count += nums[i];
    }
}
```

**RUN:**

```
~> a.out
Enter number 1: 1
Another? Enter number 2: 2
Another? Enter number 3: 3
Another? Enter number 4: 4
Another? Enter number 5: 5
Another? Enter number 6: 6
Another? Enter number 7: 7
Another? Enter number 8: 8
Another? Enter number 9:
```

It's supposed to ask me if I want to enter another number, but for some reason the scanf is not working. Also, I need to make it so that the user can enter 100 numbers, or any number under that, being prompted with a question of "do you want to enter another number". If the answer is no, it terminates, if it is yes, it carries on.

Comment: I notice that even once you get the reading a character thing sorted out you are not doing any decision making on the basis of the input...

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm doing that later, that isn't my problem. The above that I posted is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first scanf leaves a newline in the buffer. It's because `%d` ignores trailing blanks while `%c` doesn't. Use this cheap trick to make the second `scanf` eat the blanks:

```
scanf(" %c", &answer);
       ^
```

The issue is common enough, you can read more about it in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html).

Comment: A better solution is this:  scanf("%c%*c", &answer);  The asterisk tells scanf to parse the 2nd char but not to assign it to anything.

Comment: Thank you so much cnicutar. Thank you Carey Gregory as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space before the `%c` in order to skip the newline that wasn't read when scanf stopped at the end of the number.

I have some unsolicited advice...

1. Don't use `scanf(3)` directly, it's too hard to make it do what you want. It's usually better to use `fgets(3)` and then `sscanf(3)`.
2. Compile with warnings turned on. (On my Mac that means `cc -Wall ...`)

And with warnings turned on, here your program with a few issues fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int nums[100], i;
    char answer;
    int count = 0;
    // double avg;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %d", &nums[i]);
        printf("Another? ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        if (answer != 'y' && answer != 'Y')
          break;
        count += nums[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```